# Replace null to None without impacting other cases | Python

Tags: python

I have JSON cases that are the following :

```
case1 = '{"Data":{"Parties":[{"ID":"JackyID","Role":12}],"NbIDs":1}}'
case2 = '{"Data":{"Parties":[{"ID":"JackyID","Role":12},{"ID":"SamNumber","Role":122}],"NbIDs":3}}'
case3 = '{"Data":{"Parties":[],"NbIDs":0}}'
case4 = '{"Data": null}'
```

Now, I want to parse these cases using the following func :

```
import json

def parse_data(data_str):
    response = {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
    try:
        data_json = json.loads(data_str) 
    except:
        return response
    data = data_json['Data']
    if data_json['Data']:
        data = data.replace('null', 'None', inplace=True)
    for party in data_json['Data']['Parties']:
        if party['Role'] == 12:
            response['Buyer'] = party['ID']
        elif party['Role'] == 122:
            response['Seller'] = party['ID']        
    return response
```

When executing the func, an exception is raised for `parse_data(case1)`

```
<ipython-input-611-187345b4ee2c> in parse_data(data_str)
      9     data = data_json['Data']
     10     if data_json['Data']:
---> 11         data = data.replace('null', 'None', inplace=True)
     12     for party in data_json['Data']['Parties']:
     13         if party['Role'] == 12:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

And when `parse_data(case4)` :

```
<ipython-input-619-9e105920ddfb> in parse_data(data_str)
     11     if data_json['Data']:
     12         data = data.replace('null', 'None', inplace=True)
---> 13     for party in data_json['Data']['Parties']:
     14         if party['Role'] == 12:
     15             response['Buyer'] = party['ID']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this happening and how to fix please ?

Comment: I guess you are using the built-in json module, in such case the data you are loading will be of type 'dict' based on the examples you have provided.
'dict' object has no attribute 'replace' so an exception will be raised and you will always return the default response.
I would suggest logging the exception in the except block for further investigation and update the original question accordingly.

Comment: @daniel thank you for your comment. I've edited my post adding the exception.

Comment: Why does it mention Pandas in the title, and is the question tagged Pandas? I see nothing about Pandas in the question.

Comment: The problem is as it says on the tin: "'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'". It is clear (from the tag and title) that `parse_data` expects a DataFrame (or Series) as data for `data_json['Data']`, but since you pass a nested dict/list, the function won't work any more. Python is flexible, but not that flexible that it will automagically handle the new functionality that Pandas adds.

Comment: case4 is simpler: there is no inner (nested) dict, but the line `data_json['Data']['Parties']` expects there to be one (with a key of 'Parties').

Comment: `json.loads` already parses JS's `null` into Python's `None`, no need to do any replacing.

Comment: Aside: the line `data = data.replace('null', 'None', inplace=True)` is a bit silly: it changes things in place, yet assigns the result to itself. `data.replace('null', 'None', inplace=True)` would have been enough (if `data` were a dataframe or series).

Comment: @isaactfa, you are right but when parsing case4 with `null`, I have `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and when parsing with `None` it return the correct result. Give it a try!

Comment: @AmyB, don't worry, I've tried it. So in `case4` your `data_json['Data']` parses correctly to `None`. Then you try to access the field `'Parties'` as though it was a `dict` which it isn't; it's `None`. After you've parsed your data, just check if `data_json['Data'] is None` and return early if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make some checks on whether your data you search for is existent or not.
In the first part you only need the `try` & `except` block if you are not sure if you have valid json data as string.

Then when you check for your cases you need `isinstance` to check if your dictionary `data` has another `dict` as value or not.
If `true` you can check if there is the key `Parties`.
If all that is true you can go on with your `if else` whether Buyer or Seller.

```
def parse_data(data_str):
    response = {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
    try:
        data_json = json.loads(data_str) 
    except:
        return response
    data = data_json['Data']
    if isinstance(data, dict): # check if the value of data is a dict
        if data['Parties']: # check if there is a key "Parties"
            for party in data['Parties']:
                if party['Role'] == 12:
                    response['Buyer'] = party['ID']
                elif party['Role'] == 122:
                    response['Seller'] = party['ID']        
    return response
```

Run the function with all 4 cases and print them:

```
for idx,case in enumerate([case1,case2,case3,case4]):
    print(f"Case{idx+1}: ", parse_data(case))

Case1:  {'Buyer': 'JackyID', 'Seller': ''}
Case2:  {'Buyer': 'JackyID', 'Seller': 'SamNumber'}
Case3:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
Case4:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
```

This is very specific for your case. In general you need to make sure to check first what the data is before you can use methods with it (`resplace` only works if the data is a string, data["key"] only works if this `key` is existent, otherwise you will un into an error.

**UPDATE**

I think `isinstance` is needed here, because you only want to proceed if after the key "Data" there is another `dict`. If there is a list instead of a dict, the solution of @9769953 will crash because `list` has no attribute `get`. Other than that I think his solution is the better way to solve this.

This line

```
for party in data.get('Parties', []):
```

does nearly the same like my two lines

```
if data['Parties']: # check if there is a key "Parties"
            for party in data['Parties']:
```

Another way your code will crash is if in the value of `Parties` (which is here always a list of dicts) has no dict in the list (e.g only a string: `'{"Data":{"Parties":["just_a_string", "just_another_string"]}}'`.
You could check that too.
Combined with the other answer and some cases added:

```
case1 = '{"Data":{"Parties":[{"ID":"JackyID","Role":12}],"NbIDs":1}}'
case2 = '{"Data":{"Parties":[{"ID":"JackyID","Role":12},{"ID":"SamNumber","Role":122}],"NbIDs":3}}'
case3 = '{"Data":{"Parties":[],"NbIDs":0}}'
case4 = '{"Data": null}'
case5 = '{"Data":["just_list1", "just_list2", "just_list3"]}'
case6 = '{"Data":{"Parties":"string"}}'
case7 = '{"Data":{"Parties":["string", "another_string"]}}'


def parse_data(data_str):
    response = {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
    try:
        data_json = json.loads(data_str) 
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return response
    data = data_json['Data']
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        return response
    for party in data.get('Parties', []):
        if not isinstance(party, dict):
            return response
        if party['Role'] == 12:
            response['Buyer'] = party['ID']
        elif party['Role'] == 122:
                response['Seller'] = party['ID']        
    return response

for idx,case in enumerate([case1,case2,case3,case4,case5,case6,case7]):
    print(f"Case{idx+1}: ", parse_data(case))

Case1:  {'Buyer': 'JackyID', 'Seller': ''}
Case2:  {'Buyer': 'JackyID', 'Seller': 'SamNumber'}
Case3:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
Case4:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
Case5:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
Case6:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
Case7:  {'Buyer': '', 'Seller': ''}
```

Comment: Where do the extra requirements come from? E.g., checking for list types etc? I didn't see those in the question.

Comment: @9769953 that was just an add-on. seeing of the different cases and that he didn't think of (of didnt know) of checking types I added that. Wasn't a negative point at your answer, you didn't check because regarding to the example not necessary